# I want to conduct some test on a large correlation matrix in r

Tags: fisher-transform

The data I have is essentially the number of times two students were seen together.
So student 1 and 3 were seen the most amount of times together, then 2 and 3, then 1 and 2.
The correlation matrix looks like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ZRe.jpg) [2] [3]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6ZRe.jpg)  0  0.4 0.7
[2] 0.4  0  0.5
[3] 0.7 0.5 0

After reading a bit, I know you cannot average correlation coefficients, but I would like to conduct a test to have an 'average' or some value that best shows the data. Any suggestions on how I can do this in r?

[image]

Comment: How, exactly, do you compute this matrix? (NB it  is definitely *not* a correlation matrix).

Comment: Using the r package asnipe's  get_network function.